# A solution that really works for auto refresh on load

Tags: page-refresh

I have searched this site ad nausium, can't get a straight answer on what i thought was a simple question. How do I get my index or any page not to load from cache? I have tried everything from redirecting to another page, which works great, except when i change the content on that page, you have to refresh that as well, the only thing that works for sure is the refresh button, which is hideous, can any one help? i change content every week,when visitors go on the site next week, they get the same content as the week before unless they refresh. this is 2014, must be a simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

If I get what you're asking you would like any requests for your page to never load from cache, always load from source.

HTML meta tags can keep browsers from using cached files, include this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
```

Check out the [docs](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html).

Some browsers require a little more work (*cough* IE *cough*), check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) on how to support browsers.

Comment: I tried this very tag, doesn't work, tried all browsers, same result, to ask a visitor to a site to refresh a page is taking steps backward, I've got to find an answer that doesn't involve refreshing every 5 secs, that is just annoying.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on your situation a tad more. You're bouncing back and forth between cache and refresh, which are separate functions. A refresh doesn't force ignoring cache (a cache refresh does), yet your temporary fix is done via refresh. Can you provide any more details?

Comment: Every week I publish a new page, what do i have to do to make sure that every new post is seen and not the previous post rendered by the cache? I have tried the refresh button, which works, but this requires the visitor to refresh the page themselves, they shouldn't have to. I am searching for an option that eliminates the client from doing this. page redirects work to a point, except, the page that I am redirecting to, the content is cached so that page also has to be refreshed to show new content. Is there a solution that eliminates visitors refreshing the page?

Comment: Are the posts on separate pages or in a stack?

Comment: they are on separate pages. Each time I put up a new page, it becomes my index until the next page in a week, and so on. the index page is the first thing you come to on most sites, so if through cache it displays previous content, that can be frustrating. when I go to msn.com or nba.com, I don't hit a refresh button, the new content is there now matter when they update their content, that's what I am trying to achieve. I was researching the possibility of achieving this through the .htaccess file but nothing promising as yet, hoping for a simpler solution